# Callback функция в плагине JQuery

Tags: jquery

Пытаюсь сделать плагин для Jquery. Вот его максимально упрощенная версия:

```
(function($) {
  $.extend({
    VK: function(options) {

      this.init = function() {

      }

      this.init();
      // allow jQuery chaining
      return this;
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

На данный момент вызывается мой плагин след образом:

```
$.VK();
```

Я хочу создать обрабтчик события в стиле как это реализовано, например, для ajax:

```
$.VK().done(function( data ) {

}).fail(function( data ){

});
```

как это можно реализовать ? То есть вопрос заключается, как вызвать функцию done() из плагина?

Думаю нужно что-то вроде такого, но это конечно не рабоатет
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n1acb486/3/)

```
(function($) {

  $.extend({
    VK: function(options) {

      this.init = function() {

        var someCondition = true;
        if (someCondition) {
          this.done("OK")
        } else {
          this.fail("fail")
        }
      }

      this.init();
      // allow jQuery chaining
      return this;
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: `done` и `fail` это методы `Promise` или аналогичного объекта jQuery. Поэтому для их использования функция `VK` **должна** возвращать `promise` либо объект в котором есть эти функции

Comment: в Вашем коде `$.VK()` возвращает глобальный объект `jQuery`, к которому Вы еще и добавляете метод `init`.

Comment: @Igor, А что $.VK() должен возвращать?  Я просто никогда не занимался плагинами для jquery

Comment: `var result = {init: function(){...}, done: function(){...; return this; } fail: function(){...; return this;} }; return result;` И callback'ов в коде пока не видно.

Comment: а как ваш плагин связан с jQuery? почему не сделаете просто отдельный модуль?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, цель немного разобраться в плагинах jquery. но вообще, да, jquery тут не принципиален

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем благодаря вашим подсказкам пока что получилось так:

```
(function($) {

  $.extend({
    VK: function(options) {
      init = function() {

        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        var someCondition = true;

        if (someCondition) {
           deferred.resolve("ok");
        } else {
           deferred.reject("fail");         
        }

        return deferred.promise();

      }

      return init();
    }
  });
})(jQuery);


$(function() {

  $("#button").click(function() {
    $.VK().done(function(data) {
      alert(data);
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: зачем `this.` перед `init`?

Comment: @Igor, поправил, спасибо.

Comment: тогда уж var  перед ним добавь